# how to fastering the for loop command in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a large number of for loops; is there any way to make this run faster? It takes more than 30 minutes to get the scatter graph.

I was thinking to maybe use break. Is it possible or do I need to use something else to make the program run section by section?

```
A = [4/5 -1/5 -1/5 -1/5 -1/5; -1/5 4/5 -1/5 -1/5 -1/5; -1/5 -1/5 4/5 -1/5 -1/5;-1/5 -1/5 -1/5 4/5 -1/5; -1/5 -1/5 -1/5 -1/5 4/5];
B = [ 0 0 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 0 1 ; 0 0 0 1 0 ; 0 0 0 1 1 ; 0 0 1 0 0 ; 0 0 1 0 1 ];

for i = 1:size(B,1)
    p1 = A * B(1,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0a(i) = d*p1;
    qtransformation0a(i) = q*p1;

    for i = 1:size(B,1)
        p2 = A * B(2,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
        dtransformation0b(i) = d*p2;
        qtransformation0b(i) = q*p2;

        for i = 1:size(B,1)
            p3 = A * B(3,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
            dtransformation0c(i) = d*p3;
            qtransformation0c(i) = q*p3;

            for i = 1:size(B,1)
                p4 = A * B(4,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
                dtransformation0d(i) = d*p4;
                qtransformation0d(i) = q*p4;

                for i = 1:size(B,1)
                    p5 = A * B(5,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
                    dtransformation0e(i) = d*p5;
                    qtransformation0e(i) = q*p5;

                    for i = 1:size(B,1)
                        p6 = A * B(6,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
                        dtransformation0f(i) = d*p6;
                        qtransformation0f(i) = q*p6;
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

figure
scatter(dtransformation0a,qtransformation0a,100,'b.')

%text(dtransformation0a(:), qtransformation0a(:), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
% 'HorizontalAlignment','right') 
hold on 
scatter(dtransformation0b,qtransformation0b,100,'b.')

%text(dtransformation0a(:), qtransformation0a(:), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
% 'HorizontalAlignment','right')
hold on 
scatter(dtransformation0c,qtransformation0c,100,'b.')

%text(dtransformation0a(:), qtransformation0a(:), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
% 'HorizontalAlignment','right')
hold on 
scatter(dtransformation0d,qtransformation0d,100,'b.')

%text(dtransformation0a(:), qtransformation0a(:), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
% 'HorizontalAlignment','right')
hold on
scatter(dtransformation0e,qtransformation0e,100,'b.')

%text(dtransformation0a(:), qtransformation0a(:), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
% 'HorizontalAlignment','right') 
hold on
```

Comment: Why are all these loops nested in the first place? You're redefining `i` at every iteration of every loop. Wouldn't non-nested loops do the trick?

Comment: @RoneyMichael what do you meant by non-nested loops? my main interest is to do this p1 =  A * B(1,:)' -A * B(i,:)'; p2 =  A * B(2,:)' -A * B(i,:)'; and  p3 =  A * B(3,:)' -A * B(i,:)'; then scatter it in graph..

Comment: Check the answer I just posted. If it doesn't work for you, I'll take another look at it.

Comment: @RoneyMichael.i'll try..anything will let you know..thanks alot

Comment: @RoneyMichael yup its works..thanks alot man...one more thing..if let say..x-axis have the value of dtransformation0a(i), dtransformation0b(i),dtransformation0c(i) and etc and y-axis has the value of qtransformation0a(i) ,qtransformation0b(i) and qtransformation0c(i)..how can i find the similar/redundant value? is it by using find? or better to used for-loops also..

Comment: There might be a better wat to do this, but you could try putting them into separate arrays `x` and `y` and sorting them (while preserving the index if required). This should be easy enough using MATLAB's `sort` functionality (try `help sort` for details). After doing so, you could eliminate successive values within a certain "tolerance" limit as required before displaying the data.

Comment: P.S. Do upvote and accept the answer if you're satisfied with it.

Comment: @RoneyMichael how to upvote??

Comment: The up arrow right to the side of the answer. Don't worry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you need to nest all those loops since you seem to be redefining the value of `i` in each individual iteration of each individual loop. A single loop should work just as well. This should work just as well, but much, much faster.

```
A = [4/5 -1/5 -1/5 -1/5 -1/5; -1/5 4/5 -1/5 -1/5 -1/5; -1/5 -1/5 4/5 -1/5 -1/5;-1/5 -1/5 -1/5 4/5 -1/5; -1/5 -1/5 -1/5 -1/5 4/5];
B = [ 0 0 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 0 1 ; 0 0 0 1 0 ; 0 0 0 1 1 ; 0 0 1 0 0 ; 0 0 1 0 1 ];

for i = 1:size(B,1)
    p1 = A * B(1,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0a(i) = d*p1;
    qtransformation0a(i) = q*p1;
    p2 = A * B(2,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0b(i) = d*p2;
    qtransformation0b(i) = q*p2;
    p3 = A * B(3,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0c(i) = d*p3;
    qtransformation0c(i) = q*p3;
    p4 = A * B(4,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0d(i) = d*p4;
    qtransformation0d(i) = q*p4;
    p5 = A * B(5,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0e(i) = d*p5;
    qtransformation0e(i) = q*p5;
    p6 = A * B(6,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0f(i) = d*p6;
    qtransformation0f(i) = q*p6;
end

figure
scatter(dtransformation0a,qtransformation0a,100,'b.')

%text(dtransformation0a(:), qtransformation0a(:), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
% 'HorizontalAlignment','right') 
hold on 
scatter(dtransformation0b,qtransformation0b,100,'b.')

%text(dtransformation0a(:), qtransformation0a(:), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
% 'HorizontalAlignment','right')
hold on 
scatter(dtransformation0c,qtransformation0c,100,'b.')

%text(dtransformation0a(:), qtransformation0a(:), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
% 'HorizontalAlignment','right')
hold on 
scatter(dtransformation0d,qtransformation0d,100,'b.')

%text(dtransformation0a(:), qtransformation0a(:), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
% 'HorizontalAlignment','right')
hold on
scatter(dtransformation0e,qtransformation0e,100,'b.')

%text(dtransformation0a(:), qtransformation0a(:), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
% 'HorizontalAlignment','right') 
hold on
```

In other words, the time complexity has been reduced from `O(n^6)` to `O(n)`. So if you took 30 minutes before, you'll probably take around 30^(1/6) minutes, i.e., less than 2 min now.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Roney,

Do not need to Nest all Loops.

These will help reducing the time to n*6-1 (approx)